# Program works in repl.it but gets "undefined method" error in Codewars

Tags: ruby

I have been working on a codewars challenge and I want to submit it, my code works in repl.it and passes all the tests but when I run it in the codewars shell I get this error:

```
queue_time': undefined method `max' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from `block in'
    from `block in describe'
    from  `measure'
    from  `describe'
    from  `'
```

here is the code:

```
def queue_time(customers, n)
  total_queue = [] 
  i = 0 

  while i < n
    total_queue << [customers[i]]
    i += 1 
  end 

  open_queue_index = total_queue.index {|x| x == total_queue.min}
  k = n  

  while k < customers.length
    array_summed = []
    total_queue[open_queue_index] << customers[k]

      total_queue.each_index do |index|
        array_summed << total_queue[index].reduce(:+)
      end 

    open_queue_index = array_summed.index {|x| x == array_summed.min}
    k += 1 
  end 
  array_summed.max
end
```

Why won't Codewars understand the `.max` method?

Answer (score 0):

`array_summed` is not initialized.

```
while false
  array_summed = [] # initialized
end

array_summed # is nil because it was never initialized.
```

```

Comment: No, it is not out of scope. If it were, you would get a `NameError`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you, for the correction. Changed to ''not initialized''

Answer (score 0):

Your method will break if the `customers` array is empty. If that array is empty, then the method will never enter the `while k < customers.length` block, and `array_summed` will never be initialized.

Then on the last line, `array_summed.max` is basically like saying `nil.max`.

Are you passing different `customers` arrays in repl.it and codewars? If the array you're testing with in codewars is empty, then this will break.

Comment: I copied and pasted from repl.it to codewars. I added some code in the beginning to account for customers being empty or n == 0 and now I am getting this error:

    `each': comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError)
 from `min'
 from `block in queue_time'
 from  `index'
 from  `queue_time'
 from  `block in 
'
 from  `block in describe'
 from  `measure'
 from  `describe'
 from  `
'

Comment: And did that work? If not, add the code to your question so we can see it?